# Pull out name from Active Directory description

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm not sure if this will work, but I figured I'd throw it out here to see if there are any ideas. We have an OU in Active Directory for external users. These users have accounts that expire every 6 months. I've written a script to run a report every month and collect the accounts that are expiring into a text file so that I have an easy-to-read list. However, I really want to group these by the person who requested the account for the external user, because I have to email the requester and see if the account should be extended.

In the description for the external user's account, among other things, is the phrase "Requested by " followed by the name of the employee I need to email. I really want to sort my script output by these names, so it's easier to see who I need to email (and eventually I'd like to automate it all so that an email is just sent when an account is expiring).

So basically, I need PowerShell to look at the string in the description attribute, find the phrase "requested by" and then list the name. Some very terrible pseudocode might look like:

```
If substring == "requested by"
    Go one more character
    print each character until space
    go one more character (skipping the space)
    print each character until space
```

I know this is a long shot. Any tips are welcome.

EDIT: Here is an example of a description

PROJECT - Requested by John Smith 1/8/16, Expires 12/31/16

Comment: Do you have a few example description strings?

Comment: `$_.Description -replace '.*requested by (\w+) (\w+).*', '$1$2'`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I just edited the question to reflect an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression pattern to grab the names from the `Description` attribute:

```
$User = Get-ADUser external.user -Properties description
if($User.Description -match 'requested by (?<Name>\S+ \S+) ') {
    $EmployeeName = $Matches['Name']
}
```